# What are the breaking changes migrating NEST from 1.7 to 2.0?

Tags: c#, nest, elasticsearch-2.0

Is this change of the `DateFormat` to `Format` correct?

```
[ElasticProperty(DocValues = true, DateFormat = "epoch_millis")] 
-> 
[Nest.Date(DocValues = true, Format = "epoch_millis")]
```

Document path is now a required parameter of update. What is document path is this change equivalent assuming there was not document path setting the `updateSelector`?

```
elasticWriteClient.Update<T>(updateSelector);
->
elasticWriteClient.Update<T>("", updateSelector);
```

Updating the unit tests, RequestInformation and IElasticsearchResponse are gone. What is the paradigm here now?
ie this is a test initialize statement:

```
searchResponse.RequestInformation = new Mock<IElasticsearchResponse>().Object;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The releases page in github now has all the documentation concerning the breaking changes:

[Releases pages](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/releases)

[Breaking Changes page for NEST](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/docs/2.0-breaking-changes/nest-breaking-changes.md)